# Php timezone_identifier compatible database?

Tags: php, database, geolocation, timezone

In my database I would like to insert [PHP supported timezones information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) of the main cities in the world, but I can't seem to find anything near what I'm looking for.

Here's 2 examples of what I am looking for:

```
|--------------------------|
|        City table        |
|--------------------------|
| name     | timezone      |
|--------------------------|
| London   | Europe/London |
| Aberdeen | Europe/London |
|--------------------------|
```

Any idea where I can find these information?

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want [this list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php) ? The name can be extracted from the part after the slash.

Comment: Hi, I do not want the list of the PHP supported timezones, but a list or database file of the main cities in the world with their corresponding PHP supported timezones. Thanks.

Comment: If you list this and insert in into your database, that is not what you want ?

Comment: Perhaps [the GeoNames API](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) can help you better.

Comment: It's not exactly what I want because there's no "Europe/Aberdeen" for instance. The API you gave me is only working with latitude and longitude? If so that's not what I want, plus I do not want to request a distant server all the time (even if I set up some sort of caching).